# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - x)}{x} \,dx$ by contour integration

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

$$\int\limits_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \frac{\ln\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right)}{{x}}\:{\mathrm dx} \\ $$
I am trying to evaluate the above definite integral by contour integration. I have tried computing the above integral using a keyhole unit circle contour but the result is coming wrong . Please help in sorting my mistake .
The contour is attached below : [image]

My attempt to the integral is as follows :
$${I}\:=\:\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \frac{{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right)}{{x}}{dx} \\ $$
$${I}_{{C}} =\:\int_{{C}} \frac{{ln}^{\mathrm{2}} \left(\mathrm{1}−{z}\right)}{{z}}{dz} \\ $$
$$\bullet{Branch}\:{point}\Rightarrow{z}\:=\mathrm{1} \\ $$
$$\bullet{Pole}\Rightarrow{z}\:=\:\mathrm{0}\:\left({removable}\:{pole}\right) \\ $$
$${By}\:{Cauchy}'{s}\:{Theorem}\:, \\ $$
$$\int_{{C}} =\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{1}} } +\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{2}} } +\int_{\gamma} +\int_{\Gamma} =\:\mathrm{0}\:\rightarrow\left(\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $$
$$\bullet{Branch}\:{cut}\Rightarrow\left(−\infty,\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $$
$$\bullet{arg}\left(\mathrm{1}−{z}\right)\epsilon\:\left(\mathrm{0},\mathrm{2}\pi\right) \\ $$
$${Now}, \\ $$
$$\bullet\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{1}} } =\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \frac{{ln}^{\mathrm{2}} \left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right)}{{x}}{dx}={I}_{\mathrm{0}}  \\ $$
$$\bullet\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{2}} } =\int_{\mathrm{1}} ^{\mathrm{0}\left(\right.} \frac{\left.{ln}\left(\mathrm{1}−{x}\right)−\mathrm{2}\pi{i}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} }{{x}}{dx} \\ $$
$$\:=−{I}_{\mathrm{0}} +\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{1}} \frac{\mathrm{4}\pi^{\mathrm{2}} }{{x}}{dx}+\mathrm{4}\pi{iI} \\ $$
$$\therefore\:{Im}\left(\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{1}} } +\int_{\psi_{\mathrm{2}} } \right)\:=\:\mathrm{4}\pi{I}\:\:\:\rightarrow\:\left(\mathrm{2}\right) \\ $$
$$\int_{\Gamma} \Rightarrow\:{z}\:=\:\mathrm{1}+{e}^{{i}\theta}  \\ $$
$$\Rightarrow\:{dz}\:=\:{ie}^{{i}\theta} \:{d}\theta\: \\ $$
$$\theta\:=\:\mathrm{0}\:{to}\:\mathrm{2}\pi \\ $$
$$\int_{\Gamma} =\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{2}\pi} \frac{{ln}^{\mathrm{2}} \left(−{e}^{{i}\theta} \right)\centerdot{ie}^{{i}\theta} }{\mathrm{1}\:+\:{e}^{{i}\theta} }{d}\theta \\ $$
$$\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{2}\pi} \frac{\left({i}\left(\pi\:+\:\theta\right)\right)^{\mathrm{2}} \centerdot{ie}^{\frac{{i}\theta}{\mathrm{2}}} }{\mathrm{2}\:{cos}\left(\frac{\theta}{\mathrm{2}}\right)}{d}\theta \\ $$
$$\left\{\mathrm{1}+{e}^{{i}\theta} \:=\:\mathrm{2}{cos}\left(\frac{\theta}{\mathrm{2}}\right){e}^{{i}\left(\frac{\theta}{\mathrm{2}}\right)} \right\} \\ $$
$$\therefore\:\:\:\mid{Im}\left(\:\int_{\Gamma} \right)\mid \\ $$
$$=\int_{\mathrm{0}} ^{\mathrm{2}\pi} \frac{\left(\pi\:+\:\theta\right)^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{2}}{d}\theta \\ $$
$$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\:\:\frac{\mathrm{13}\pi^{\mathrm{3}} }{\mathrm{3}}\:\rightarrow\:\left(\mathrm{3}\right) \\ $$
$${From}\:\left(\mathrm{1}\right),\left(\mathrm{2}\right)\:{and}\:\left(\mathrm{3}\right),\:{we}\:{get} \\ $$
$$\Rightarrow\mathrm{4}\pi{I}\:+\:\frac{\mathrm{13}\pi^{\mathrm{3}} }{\mathrm{3}}\:=\:\mathrm{0} \\ $$
$$\Rightarrow\:{I}\:=\:−\frac{\mathrm{13}\pi^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{12}}\: \\ $$
$$ \\ $$
$$ \\ $$
$$ \\ $$

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The OP is asking about contour integration.

Comment: jjagmath:  Yes... and I'm giving (in a comment) the answer, so that the OP can check/confirm any candidate answer found.

Comment: There is no pole at $0$, so you can take contours that include $0$.

Comment: @jjagmath yes we might not consider z=0 pole as the residue of the function at the pole evaluates to 0 .

Comment: In case it's helpful, substituting $x\mapsto\dfrac x{1+x}$ gives the equivalent form$$-\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\,dx$$which may lend ideas for other potential contours.

Comment: @user170231 I have also dealt with this form also but failed to find any appropriate contour for that as well

Comment: Also integrating by parts gives$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\frac x{1+x}}{1+x}\,dx$$but this introduces another branch point...

Comment: @user170231 please notice in this new substituted case,  the residue at z=-1 evaluates to (i × infinity)

Comment: @user170231 Also integrating along the branch cut [0, infinity) gives an intermediate divergent integral which creates a mess.

Comment: Right, that won't work because $-1$ is also a branch point.

Comment: Yes, it can be solved by contour integral. I can write a solution if nobody wrote...

Comment: You can integrate over [this contour](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lpx3njswyv) where the branch cut starts at $z=1$ and the logarithm's argument is in the interval $(-\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$.

Comment: And when you drag the $r$ slider towards $0$, the small circular arc also gets smaller and its contour integral should converge to $0$, making up for the fact that there is no removable singularity at $z = 1$ unlike at $z=0$.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes , indeed it's a great contour to work with . Thanks a lot.Let me try integrating over the contour on my own.It would also be a great help if you can work out your idea and post here as an answer.

Comment: That contour I made up is sort of like Ace's contour, but I constructed it specifically that way in the Desmos link to avoid non-holomorphic stuff. After you prove that the contour integral of the small circular arc around $z=1$ converges to $0$ as $r \to 0^+$, then you can follow what Ace did, but you can't use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) on Ace's quarter-pie contour because the integrand blows up at $z=1$.

Comment: Also, for that smaller circular arc, maybe it's easier to use $\left(-r\cos t+1,r\sin t\right)$ for $t \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-r^{2}}\right)\right]$.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes , the contour is quite interesting. Moreover such contours like unit quater circle , box contours are quite rare .

Comment: After reading your updated attempt, there are a lot of notation issues that seem borderline wrong. It's hard to follow and it'd take me a while to write a full-fledged answer (if I can), but the first thing I'm noticing is that if you were to define your arg to be in $(-\pi, \pi)$, then your branch cut would actually be on $[1,\infty)$ instead of $(-\infty,1]$ because of that negative sign in front of the $z$. So you would need to have your branch cut oriented exactly how you have it in the picture and figure out an interval for your arg to reside in using that branch cut.

Comment: @Accelerator Ok..I will rectify it . But irrespective of the individual argument of the function along each path above and below the branch cut , will not  the change in argument of the function about the branch cut be still (-2 times pi ) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Accelerator The arg(1-z) should belong to (0 , 2 pi) for the branch cut      (-infinity, 1)...isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @Accelerator But even after rectifying the argument range , essentially the limits of integration for the circle ( big gamma denoted in the figure ) gets altered . This too doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147094/discussion-between-sourav-and-accelerator).

Answer (score 5):

Integrate around a quarter circle, i.e. $0\to 1 \to i\to 0$. Then
\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}xdx\\
=& \ \Re \int_0^i \frac{\ln(1-x)}xdx
 + \Re \int_i^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}xdx\\
=& \ \Re \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-it)}t dt 
 + \Im \int_0^{\frac\pi2} {\ln(1-e^{it})}dt\\
=&\ \frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+t^2)}tdt
 + \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\left(\frac t2-\frac\pi2\right)dt\\
=&\ \frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+t)}tdt
- \frac{3\pi^2}{16}
\end{align}
Note that $\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1-t^2)}tdt
=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1-t)}tdt=\frac12I$ and
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+t)}tdt
= \int_0^1\frac{\ln (1-t^2)}tdt
-\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1-t)}tdt
=-\frac12 I
$$
So, we have
$$I=-\frac18 I -\frac{3\pi^2}{16}=-\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: That's a great approach you have employed for the given integral . I am highly intrigued by your approach of a unit quarter circle in evaluating a definite integral .However,  I am a beginner in complex analysis.  It would be extremely helpful if you can precisely explain your steps .Thanks a lot .

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there is a branch cut originating at $x=1$. Instead of directly having the contour over it, you could make some indented path as a workaround (pun intended) where the integral over it converges to $0$ as the path shrinks. From there, your answer should work.

Comment: @Accelerator Please suggest how ? I think it would have been useful if the limits were from 1 to infinity. We could have have then used a keyhole contour .

Comment: @SOURAV You can use the small circular arc I shared in the Desmos link.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes , I will be working on it a little later .Yes that approach should work .I'm saying that integration around a branch cut is likely impossible in this case .

Comment: @Ace What does the symbol ℜ
denote here ?

Comment: @SOURAV - It denotes the real part of the integrals.

Comment: @Ace Why did you consider the real part of ln(1-(e^it)) instead of (i×ln(1-(e^it))) , because on parametrizing          
 z = (e^it))) , we get the expression (i×ln(1-(e^it))) .

Comment: @SOURAV you should get the real part of $i \ln(1-e^{it})$.

Comment: @Accelerator I have edited my question with my attempt .

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Changing variable to $$u = -\log(1 - x)$$ transforms the integral to
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{u \,du}{e^u - 1}.$$

Now evaluate $$\oint_{\Gamma_{\epsilon, R}} \frac{z^2\,dz}{e^z - 1},$$ where $\Gamma_{\epsilon, R}$ is the contour indicated by the diagram, both by the Residue Theorem and by parameterizing the constituent arcs, and compute the imaginary part.
[image]
(N.b. the exponent in the numerator is $2$; the reason for this choice of integrand becomes apparent when you parameterize each of the arcs and simplify.) The indentation at $0$ isn't really necessary, since the singularity of the integrand there is removable and so the integrand extends to be analytic there.

The computation is similar to the one in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/700715/155629), but note that the difference of sign in the denominator changes the location of the singularities and hence the location(s) of the circular arcs.

> The value of the original integral is $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Can't the given integral be evaluated in its very original  form (avoiding any substitution) over an appropriate contour ? Actually I am interested in way that avoids any substitution of the given integral .

Comment: @SOURAV Sure; informally we can just integrate $$\int_\gamma \frac{\log (1 - w)^2 \,dw}{w},$$ where $\gamma$ is the image of $\Gamma_{\epsilon, R}$ under the transformation $w = 1 - e^{-z}$ (which reverses the substitution, this time regarding the variables as complex). Here $\gamma$ should look something like a circle of radius $1$ centered at $1$ with a detour around the branch cut of $w \mapsto \log(1 - w)$ on $(-\infty, 1]$. (A bit more formally, our contour in $w$ should avoid the branch cut, but doing so is a standard operation.) Then, apply the Residue Theorem as usual.

Comment: That said, it may not be meaningful to "avoid substitution" when applying the Residue Theorem to evaluate a definite integral like this---after all, parameterizing any (all) of the constituent arcs is essentially applying substitution(s) to the contour integral.

Comment: @TravisWillse...Yes sir , I should have been a more precise.I essentially meant to avoid any substitution to the real integral , not to avoid parametrization of the complex integrand along the contour in the complex plane .

Answer (score 2):

Per OP's request, here's an answer that does not apply a substitution before setting up the contour integral (see the comments under my other answer). (It's essentially the same as my other solution, but rewritten in terms of the complex extension $w = 1 - e^{-z}$ of the original variable $x$ of integration.)

**Hint** Let $\gamma_{\epsilon, \alpha}$ be the indicated modified keyhole contour, where the angles between the line segments and the $x$-axis are $\alpha$ and the radii of the small arcs ("indentations") are $\epsilon$, and the large arc has radius $1$, and evaluate the integral
$$\oint_{\gamma_{\epsilon, \alpha}} \frac{\log^2 (1 - w) \,dw}{w} $$ using the Residue Theorem. In the diagram, the red line denotes the branch cut of $w \mapsto \log(1 - w)$, where the argument function takes values in $[0, 2\pi)$. As in the other answer, the indentation near the origin in the upper half-plane is unnecessary, as the integrand remains bounded as $z \to 0$ within the upper half-plane, but the symmetry afforded by its presence makes some algebraic manipulation easier.
[image]

> The value of the original integral is $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can post a complete solution using the keyhole contour approach mentioned above above.

Comment: I looked at the solution that you edited into your question, and it looks to me that you haven't accounted for the lower indentation at $0$. On that bottom side, the integrand behaves as $\frac{(2 \pi i)^2}{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}$, so the small arc contributes a nonzero quantity.

Comment: Ok sir , I am looking into it . Thanks a lot for pointing out . Other than the integration about the arc which I have missed , are rest of my solution correct ?