# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - x)}{x} {\mathrm dx}$ by contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

$$
\int\limits_{0} ^{1} 
\frac{\ln\left(1−{x}\right)}{{x}}\:{\mathrm dx}
$$
I am trying to evaluate the above definite integral by contour integration. I have tried computing the above integral using a square box contour of unit sides viz. $([0,1];[1,(1+i)];[(1+i),i];[i,0])$ with small quater circle intendations at $z=0$ and $z=1$, in order to avoid the pole and branch point on the real axis. But this contour is not giving fruitful results to evaluate the integral. It would be my pleasure if you all can suggest ways to evaluate the given integral by contour integration.

Comment: How did this integral arise?

Comment: A much easier way to evaluate this integral is by expanding it as a power series. You get $-\zeta(2)$, which is $-\pi^2/6$.

Comment: You asked this [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729907/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-ln1-xx-dx-by-contour-integratio) yesterday.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes , today I posted this question to mathoverflow to get some other opinions . But they found this question inappropriate for that site and so they migrated the question here . Moreover I have tried your approach of unit quater circle but I am ending up getting wrong answer . It will be helpful if you can work out the problem in answer .

Comment: My answer would be identically the same as the other answerer who came up with the quarter-pie idea. The only difference would be that I parameterize that smaller circular arc and show its contour integral converges to $0$. Other than that, my answer would practically be a duplicate.

Comment: @Accelerator I had doubts in some of his steps...which I have asked him there but are still unanswered.

Comment: In that Desmos link from yesterday, I defined any path $z(t)$ as $(x(t), y(t))$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\int_{\text{smaller circular arc}} f(z)dz = \int_{\text{the bounds of t you saw}} f(z(t)) z'(t)dt$. There should be some small radius $r$ when you write it out, and so you would have to let $r$ approach $0$. That's one option. Another is using the ML-inequality by finding an upper bound for the integral in absolute values and the arc length of the path, then using the Squeeze Theorem, and maybe a few things here and there.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a nice way to use that unit square contour idea, per this post, and share the answer on yesterday's post. Also, even though it's mathematically valid to have a quarter-circle indentation at $z=0$, you don't need that indentation and you can just have the contour directly on it, but you would need one at $z=1$.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks a lot in advance. It would be extremely helpful for me .

Answer (score 1):

Denote $x=t^2$, this gives
$$
I:=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t^2)}{t^2}2tdt=2I+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}tdt.
$$
Thus $$J:=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}xdx=I-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}xdx=\frac32I,$$
and we proceed with computing $J$.

For this end, we change the contour $[-1,1]$ to the upper semicircle to get
$$
J=-\int_{0}^\pi \frac{\ln(1-e^{is})}{e^{is}}d(e^{is})
=-i\int_{0}^\pi \ln(-2i\sin(s/2)e^{is/2})d(s)\\=-i\int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin(s/2))ds-i\int_0^\pi i(s/2-\pi/2)ds\\=
-i\int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin(s/2))ds-\pi^2/4=-\pi^2/4,
$$
the last equality since $J$ is real. Thus $I=-\pi^2/6$.